# Which Ip Camera

Tags: android, camera, ip-camera

**Hi everbody!**
I would build a drone with a ip camera to  stream video to an android app with (if  possible) http protocol (as in webpage) and the camera should be must **small** (and **light**) is possible . So, which ip camera you advice me? 
Thank you guys!

Comment: Here is a list :http://appcrawlr.com/android-apps/best-apps-ip-cam-viewer

Answer (score 0):

If it was up to me to decide, (keeping in mind that I don't know the exact size of the drone),
I would say that you can't go wrong with a Raspberry Pi and the Pi Face camera. It offers HD quality with is vital if you want to see clearly while the wind is blowing it side to side.

It is soon available in infrared so there is an add on to look forward to!!!
   It is lightweight and can be mounted anywhere because it isn't restricted to a housing.

I have used the cam for many projects from motion detection to security cams.

It is a Must Have, it is inexpensive and great for these projects, plus they can be programmed to do so much more.

Comment: The raspberry was an alternative but the it's configuration and build a low-level trasmission through wifi leads me in a trouble :/